Triple integral of change order

can I change integral order with this question?
I need to change dzdxdy -> dxdzdy

Why do you need to change the order?

that's my homework...

Healthy homework. You only have to change the order of $dz$ and $dx,.$ Concentrate on the $dz,dx$ integral only. In the screenshot $z$ runs from $0$ to $x,.$ When you change the order you have to figure out what the range of $x$ is when $z$ is given.

When doing triple integrals you can think of the order of integration like travelling along straight lines in each direction.
So for $dzdxdy$ you first travel in the $z$ direction between $0$ and $x$ - this is a line integral and gives a different value for every point in the $xy$ plane - note how the upper limit for $z$ depends on $x$ because at a different value of $z$ the edge of the shape is at a different value $x$. Then you travel in the $x$ direction between $y^2$ and $1$ - this is now a surface integral and gives a different value for every point on the $y$ axis. Finally you travel in the $y$ direction between $-1$ and $1$ to get the volume integral over the whole region.
You could indeed do this in a different order, but you need to pay close attention to the limits of your integrals - you can't just swap them for the current ones. If you want to do $dxdzdy$, first you need to figure out the limits for $x$ in terms of $y$ and/or $z$ and/or constants, then you figure out the limits for $z$ in terms of $y$ and/or constants, then you have the limits for $y$.

I found that x runs z to 1, but i don't imagine the projection of zy-plane, which means the domain of E. If  y is -1 to 1 and z is y^2 to 1, I can't got the same answer. Which part I missed?

@YellowSmy you are just making your life super difficult. The x integration will be from $\text{Max}(z,y^2)$ to 1, which is horrible, but the z integration will be something simple. However, it still is not what you think it is.

I know the z intergration first is crazy simple, but changing order itself is my homework... I should solve that way

yeah, it's definitely much more complicated if you do $x$ first, but if that's the question then that's the question. As naturallyInconsistent said, the $z$ bounds are much simpler than $[y^2, 1]$. If $x$ is $\max(z,y^2)$ then both the $x=z$ and $x=y^2$ bounds are catered for... so what do you think $z$ needs to be to cover the desired region?

I wonder if saying "limits for $z$ in terms of $y$" in my answer is throwing you off... don't forget the limits could just be constants

I'm really sorry, can I just get a entire answer? what is the Max(z,y^2)?
I'm not a native english user, so I forgot or misunderstood something. it's better to see the entire formula and think it in draw.

max(z, y^2) means I divide domain into two part, and intergrating partly?

Yeah, you're on to something there. But do you understand which of the integrals you need to split in two?

I think y should be seperated, but I still don't know exactly condition

The $x$ limits are non-trivial, because the left-hand edge of the volume is piecewise. In some parts of the $yz$ plane $x=z$, but in others $x=y^2$. The intersection of these surfaces is the surface $z=y^2$; above this (i.e. for $z>y^2$) the boundary is $x=z$, whereas below it ($y^2>z$) the boundary is $x=y^2$. Therefore the boundary is given by $x=\max(y^2,z)$. See the Desmos graph here to see this more clearly.
So $x\in[\max(y^2,z),1]$. Then we need to make sure the lower limit for $x$ is $\le1$, which means both $y^2$ and $z$ need to be $\le1$, so $y\in[-1,1]$ and $z\in[0,1]$. Then the integral is $$\rho\int\limits_{-1}^1\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_{\max(y^2,z)}^1\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}z\,{\rm d}y.$$
The $x$ integral is trivial: $$\int\limits_{\max(y^2,z)}^1\,{\rm d}x = 1-\max(y^2,z),$$ but then we have to be careful with the $z$ integral: $$\int\limits_0^1\left(1-\max(y^2,z)\right)\,{\rm d}z.$$ In different parts of the domain, the integrand is a different function. When $0\le z\le y^2$, $\max(y^2,z)=y^2$, whereas when $y^2\le z\le 1$, $\max(y^2,z)=z$, so the integral is $$\int\limits_0^{y^2}\left(1-y^2\right)\,{\rm d}z+\int\limits_{y^2}^1\left(1-z\right)\,{\rm d}z = \left(1-y^2\right)y^2+\left[z-\frac{z^2}{2}\right]_{y^2}^1 = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-y^4\right).$$
Finally, the $y$ integral is $$\frac{\rho}{2}\int\limits_{-1}^1\left(1-y^4\right)\,{\rm d}y = \frac{4\rho}{5}.$$
